# MongoDB only lets me connect remotely without authentication, even with auth = true in configuration file

Tags: mongodb, authentication

Logging into MongoDB from within the hosting machine works just fine, but if I try to login from a remote location it lets me into the shell only if I don't provide username and password. Es:

```
$ mongo AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/dbname 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.11
connecting to: AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/dbname
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: not authorized on admin to execute command { getLog: "startupWarnings" }
>
```

But if I try to provide credentials (which work perfectly from within the host):

```
$ mongo AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:27017/dbname -u username -p password
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.11
connecting to: AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:27017/dbname
Tue Jun 23 11:32:35.967 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
$
```

My config file does not have any bind IP set, auth is set to true, only thing that comes to my mind is that mongo-shell version on the host machine (the working one) is 3.0.1, while the remote client has 2.4.11. Does anybody have a clue about what's happening?

Comment: Show us an example of the create user command you are using. I have never tried to log in without auth being enabled and I bet the error message would be different but double check it anyway. I use keyfiles for the cluster so auth is implicitly enabled for me. If I do not use authenticationDatabase I cannot log in.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue with MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9 trying to connect to a remote MongoDB Server version: 3.0.6

Removing MongoDB shell version 2.4.9 and installing MongoDB shell version 3.0.6 resolved the problem entirely.

My client machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 and I ended up with MongoDB shell version 2.4.9 after running `sudo apt-get install mongo-clients` which is of course not the [suggested method of installing MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) so I removed version 2.4.9 and installed version 3.0.6 on the client as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb-clients
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-shell
```

After which, connecting to the remote MongoDB Server that previously failed now worked just fine (using bash history to re-execute the command that previously threw an auth fail)

Comment: Thanks for this. I would never have thought of doing what you did. It solved some weird problems.

Comment: @Houghtelin: you simply rocks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing the --authenticationDatabase option in mongo AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:27017/dbname -u username -p password. The value should be the database to which the user belongs.

Comment: Actually I only need to perform read/write operations, so the whole purpose was to create a non-admin user to do that safely from a node driver client. Also, just gave it a try, same exact result.

Comment: I am not sure what the reference to an admin versus a non-admin is for. I am referring to authentication of the user you are attempting to log in with. 
--authenticationDatabase <dbname> specifies the database that holds the user’s credentials. It was not something specific to an admin user or any roles the user may be granted. Here's the reference. [link]http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#cmdoption--authenticationDatabase[link]